# Getting TextField Text On Button Click

Tags: ios

I am developing an IOS App. I am creating a text field and a button dynamically, and I want to get textfield's text on button click, but I'm getting an error:

> [UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)customFieldAdd:(id)sender{
    [_addfieldArray addObject:_field];

    x = 10;
    y = 10;
    for( int i = 0; i < [_addfieldArray count]; i++ ) {
        UITextField *copyfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, x + _field.frame.size.height, 195.0f, 30.0f)];
        [copyfield setDelegate:self];
        [copyfield setTag:i];
        [_filterPossibleValueView addSubview:copyfield];
        x = x+_field.frame.size.height+10;

        UIButton *copyAddButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(202.0f, y + _addField.frame.size.height, 30.0f, 30.0f)];
        [copyAddButton setTag:i];
        [copyAddButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customFieldDelete:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_filterPossibleValueView addSubview:copyAddButton];
        y = y+_addField.frame.size.height+10;

        count++;
    }
}

- (IBAction)customFieldDelete:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSInteger index = button.tag;
//   [_addfieldArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];

    UITextField *field = [_filterPossibleValueView viewWithTag:index];
    NSString *myText = field.text;
}
```

Comment: mistake in tag that you given by button fix it your problem will be solved

Comment: `UITextField *field = [_filterPossibleValueView viewWithTag:index];` This line of code is returning `UIView` not an `UITextField`. Please check your tag.

Answer (score 0):

[The default value for the `tag` property is `0`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag), and you are setting that value to one of the text fields. So, when you try to get the view with `tag == 0`, it will have more than one view with that tag.

You should use an offset when setting the tag:

```
[copyfield setTag:kOffset + i];
...
[copyAddButton setTag:kOffset*2 + i]; // note that the button and the text field should not have the same tag either
```

where `kOffset` is defined (for example) like this:

```
let kOffset: Int = 1000
```

Then, to get the text field's text, you can use:

```
NSInteger tag = button.tag - kOffset;
UITextField *field = [_filterPossibleValueView viewWithTag:tag];
NSString *myText = field.text;
```

Comment: UITextField *field = [_filterPossibleValueView viewWithTag:index];
    NSString *myText = field.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",myText);    How to Detect TextField Text on Button Click